# Unable to install OpenFST Python extension

Tags: python, openfst

I was trying to install OpenFST Python extension according to [this](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/PythonExtension) guide. There were two options for doing this. 
The 1st option one was to issue `--enable-python` during configuration of OpenFst, which I tried and failed.
So I went for the 2nd option. I successfully installed OpenFST with these commands:

```
./configure --enable-far
make
sudo make install
```

Then I tried to install PyPi package `openfst` with `pip`: 
`pip install openfst`
and got the following error:

```
Collecting openfst
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/6b/cc05392480e2232e176be895b9ca2b9f4a5f153f99ab276b37d440b3bace/openfst-1.6.6.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: openfst
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for openfst ... error
  Complete output from command /home/arif/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-7y6dl6o2/openfst/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-zadciiwk --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'pywrapfst' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  gcc -pthread -B /home/arif/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/arif/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c pywrapfst.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pywrapfst.o -std=c++11 -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-unused-function
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  pywrapfst.cc:557:40: fatal error: fst/extensions/far/getters.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for openfst
  Running setup.py clean for openfst
Failed to build openfst
Installing collected packages: openfst
  Running setup.py install for openfst ... error
    Complete output from command /home/arif/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-7y6dl6o2/openfst/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-3niypfz6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pywrapfst' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    gcc -pthread -B /home/arif/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/arif/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c pywrapfst.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pywrapfst.o -std=c++11 -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-unused-function
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    pywrapfst.cc:557:40: fatal error: fst/extensions/far/getters.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/arif/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-7y6dl6o2/openfst/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-3niypfz6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-7y6dl6o2/openfst/
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

I am using `python 3.6 (anaconda)` and `OpenFST-1.5.4` in `Linux Mint 18.3`.

Comment: There are two different reasons this could be failing, and it's hard to guess which it is. Either your `fst` package isn't on the include path (whether that's supposed to be the default include path, or something discovered by the setup.py script, I don't know), or it is but it doesn't have the file in question. Presumably you know where `fst` is installed, right? Can you check whether `/path/to/fst/extensions/far/getters.h` exists, so we can rule out the second one?

Comment: Meanwhile, how did `--enable-python` fail? It might be easier to fix that

Comment: Also, from a quick look at [the forum](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/Forum/FstForum), it looks like [Python 3 may not be officially supported, but a user has figured out how to get it to work, so you could copy what they did](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/Forum/FstForum#python3_and_configure), Also, [despite being documented, the `pip install` method may be "out of date" and not work](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/Forum/FstForum#Python_installation_difficulties).

Comment: [This thread](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/Forum/FstForum#Python_extension_compilation_err) also says "There's no reason to call pip. The version up there is not compatible with arbitrary OpenFst versions. If you do --enable-python then make and make install, you have already installed pywrapfst for whatever version of OpenFst you're building." So I think it really is not actually supported, despite being documented, and you're better off trying the `--enable-python` method.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for your suggestions.
I looked into `fst/extensions/far/` directory, and `getters.h` file is missing.
I'll look into the links you provided. BTW, the `--enable-python` option gave me [this  error](https://pastebin.com/XDsXT0g1) (I've copied the last few lines). Any suggestion here? Sorry for disturbing you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

---

First, as far as I can tell, despite being documented, the `pip install` method really isn't supported, or even expected to work. Kyle Gorman (who I assume is one of the main authors) has commented on multiple forum threads with replies like:

> ["Using `pip` for this doesn't make much sense, and that's out of date anyways."](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/Forum/FstForum#Python_installation_difficulties)
>
> ["There's no reason to call pip. The version up there is not compatible with arbitrary OpenFst versions. If you do --enable-python then make and make install, you have already installed pywrapfst for whatever version of OpenFst you're building."](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/Forum/FstForum#Python_extension_compilation_err)

---

Second, despite saying that it works with "any Python 2.7 or later", it actually only works only with Python 2.7 exactly:

> ["Before submitting you may want to test Python 3 with the Python extension. We still develop on Python 2.7, exclusively, unfortunately, and it's not tested on Python 3."](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/Forum/FstForum#python3_and_configure)

And, in fact, that's exactly why your attempt at using `--enable-python` failed:

```
checking for a version of Python >= '2.1.0'...   File "<string>", line 1
    import sys, string;         ver = string.split(sys.version)[0];     print ver >= '2.1.0'
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
no
```

Their autoconf test for Python 2.1 or later is using syntax that's illegal in Python 3. And it doesn't do very good error handling, so it takes that `SyntaxError` to mean that your Python is 2.0 or earlier, and therefore it aborts the configure.

---

If you look further down the same thread, a user, NurL, posted:

> After a lot of tweaks to the configuration file and Makefile I managed to successfully install the Python extension for Python 3. See this Dockerfile: https://gist.github.com/0xnurl/6f97eb39409ea48db31fe315fd1e208f

I obviously can't vouch for whether this works.

And, unless you're using exactly the same target as NurL, you'll have to read through that giant `RUN wget` command line, break it into steps, and do the equivalent steps yourself.

And there may be issues that NurL didn't run into that you will. (I'd strongly suggest at least running `2to3` on the resulting code before or after installing to make sure it doesn't find anything.)

But this is as close as you're likely to get to something that works out of the box, given that what you're trying to do isn't supported. If you can't get it working for yourself from there, you probably just can't use this library.